# Hosting django in webfaction

Tags: python, django, web-deployment, webfaction

I am hosting the Django project in webfaction, I followed **https://docs.webfaction.com/software/django/getting-started.html**

As mentioned in the above link I deleted the myproject default project folder created when adding the Django app in webfaction.

problem is I entered my domain name in the browser and I got the **URL not found error**. I checked the **error.log** file I found something like **WSGI script not found in myproject folder**(but I already removed the myproject folder as mentioned in above link).

httpd.conf(appche settings)

```
WSGIDaemonProcess vyan_tender processes=2 threads=12 python-path=/home/sivagctece/webapps/vyan_tender:/home/sivagctece/webapps/vyan_tender/vyantender/vyan_tender:/home/sivagctece/webapps/vyan_tender/lib/python2.7
WSGIProcessGroup vyan_tender
WSGIRestrictEmbedded On
WSGILazyInitialization On
WSGIScriptAlias / /home/sivagctece/webapps/vyan_tender/vyantender/vyan_tender/vyan_tender/wsgi.py
```

wsgi.py file path I mentioned in httpd.conf file is from vyan_tender project

```
WSGIScriptAlias / /home/sivagctece/webapps/vyan_tender/vyantender/vyan_tender/vyan_tender/wsgi.py
```

but in the error.log file I got WSGI script not found in myproject folder(deleted)

```
[Fri Jan 04 09:32:54.434127 2019] [wsgi:error] [pid 186346:tid 
140172880013056] [client 127.0.0.1:32788] Target WSGI script not found or 
unable to stat: /home/sivagctece/webapps/vyan_tender/myproject
```

django project wsgi.py file looks like

```
import os
from django.core.wsgi import get_wsgi_application
os.environ.setdefault("DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE", "vyan_tender.settings")
application = get_wsgi_application()
```

Can anyone help me why wsgi.py pointing to myproject folder even though it is not present, how can I resolve this issue. I googled a lot but no use

Comment: Did you restart apache?

Comment: yes, I did everything

Comment: Did you manage to find a solution? If you login to console and do an `ls /home/sivagctece/webapps/vyan_tender/vyantender/vyan_tender/vyan_tender/wsgi.py` is the path/file found?